# C'est facile à faire / C'est facile de le faire

Tags: grammaire

## Difference between the two sentences?

- C'est facile à faire.
- C'est facile de le faire.

Hi there, is there anyone who can tell me the difference between the meaning of these two sentences?

I do understand that the first sentence means "It is easy to do". And may be the second sentence means "It is easy to do 'it'" : just addition of a direct object. If my speculation is correct why does the preposition differ from one another??

Comment: It's not just addition of a direct object. In *it is easy to do*, the *it* is the thing done - but in *it is easy to do it*, the first *it* is a dummy subject like in *it is raining*. These are quite different structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *C'est facile à faire*, *c'* replaces a previously mentioned subject (its antecedent). In this type of construction, the preposition has to be *à*.

In *C'est facile de le faire*, *c'* is a dummy subject - it's not replacing anything. (Just as when we say It's raining, "it" doesn't replace anything.) In this example, *le* is replacing the antecedent. When you have a dummy subject, the preposition has to be *de*.

This is just one of the particularities of [French impersonal expressions](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/using-impersonal-expressions/).

Comment: The rule given by your reference is correct, however, two of the examples used in that rule are not; "*Il est important à comprendre.*" and "*C’est important à comprendre.*" are not idiomatic. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=c%27est+important+%C3%A0+comprendre%2Cil+est+important+%C3%A0+comprendre&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=.

Comment: Thank you, it's corrected.

Comment: What's the difference then between *c'est difficile de dire si on a volé un Ballon d'or à Ronaldo* and *c'est difficile à dire si Rafael Nadal va gagner ce Roland-Garros*? Would they still be analysed as having different structures?

Comment: The difference is that "c'est difficile à dire si... " is wrong - it should be "c'est difficile de dire si..." As I explained above, à isn't followed by a clause in thes sorts of constructions.